# Telerik RadComboBox with angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, telerik, radcombobox

I have this Telerik RadComboBox and i want to bind it to angular js. I tried this

```
<telerik:RadComboBox 
    Width="100%" 
    ID="rcbPosition" 
    EmptyMessage="Please select position"
    EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
    ShowMoreResultsBox="True"
    ng-model="Employee.PositionID"
    EnableVirtualScrolling="True"
    runat="server">
    <WebServiceSettings 
        Path="~/WebService/wsPosition.asmx"
        Method="GetPositions"></WebServiceSettings>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

but no luck.. any help please.

Comment: What is the error? What is the response from the service? Have you compared both your setup and the network requests with this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx? Have you tried using RadClientDataSource: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/client-side-data-binding/defaultcs.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Telerik's Ajax controls do not support Angular directives. That's why your code is not working. Perhaps this will work for you.`<telerik:RadComboBox 
    Width="100%" 
    ID="rcbPosition" 
    EmptyMessage="Please select position"
    EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
    ShowMoreResultsBox="True"
    SelectedValue="Employee.PositionID"
    EnableVirtualScrolling="True"
    runat="server">
    <WebServiceSettings 
        Path="~/WebService/wsPosition.asmx"
        Method="GetPositions"></WebServiceSettings>
</telerik:RadComboBox>`